# Coding a Grammar with ANTLR (Mutual-Left Recursion)

Tags: antlr3

I have this grammar for code in ANTLR.

```
    grammar Booleanos;

    //lexico

    AND        : 'AND' || 'and' ;
    OR         : 'OR' || 'or' ;
    NOT        : 'NOT' || 'not';
    TRUE       : 'TRUE' || 'true' ;
    FALSE      : 'FALSE' || 'false' ;
    LPAREN     : '(' ;
    RPAREN     : ')' ;

    //sintactico

    start   :    bexpr;
    bexpr   :    bexpr OR bterm | bterm;
    bterm   :    bterm AND bfactor | bfactor;
    bfactor :    NOT bfactor | LPAREN bexpr RPAREN | TRUE | FALSE;
```

But i have a problem of Mutual-Left Recursion on bexpr: and bterm: . How can i remove this warnings? I can't compile. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

ANTLR3 cannot implicitly handle this situation, hence you get the errors. With ANTLR4 direct left recursion (those not spreading over multiple rules) are handled automatically. So if you can upgrade, consider that.

However, it's not that difficult to solve left recursion. The simplest way is probably to use [ANTLRWorks 1.5](http://www.antlr3.org/works/index.html) which has a menu entry to start resolving left recursion.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to rewrite your bexpr and bterm rules like this:

```
bexpr   :    bterm (OR bterm)*;
bterm   :    bfactor (AND bfactor)*;
```